# MongoDB access data without Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

Is there any way to execute a mongo query without the java driver, and get the raw string response in java?

What protocol is used by the mongo server <---> mongo client?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If it's only about **querying** (*not insert, update, or remove operations*), you can use [simple REST API](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#simple-rest-api) included in `mongod` process.
 It is generally used for monitoring, alert scripts, and administrative tasks

Examples:

- To get the contents of a collection:

  `http://127.0.0.1:28017/databaseName/collectionName/`
- To add a limit:

  `http://127.0.0.1:28017/databaseName/collectionName/?limit=-10`
- To skip:

  `http://127.0.0.1:28017/databaseName/collectionName/?skip=5`
- To query for {a : 1}:

  `http://127.0.0.1:28017/databaseName/collectionName/?filter_a=1`

As per mongo's documentation:

> This API is disabled by default, as it could provide unauthenticated access to data. Use **--rest** on the command line to enable, but be aware of security implications

Check [details](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--rest) to enable this.

Comment: This an API provided by MongoDB but it is AFAIK not the one used by MongoDB Java driver (at least in the current version)

Comment: @Robert I did not say it is used by MongoDB Java driver.

Comment: @Robert OP wants to execute a mongo query without the java driver. So, REST could be a way.

Comment: this look promising, i only ned to test the Performance drawbacks over the direct socket access.

Answer (score 2):

The Mongo Java Driver uses the "[MongoDB Wire protocol](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/)".
It is a socket oriented BSON communication protocol.

You can see/examine it for example in Wireshark when you connect to a MongoDB database that does not use SSL/TLS (filter for TCP port 27017).